# Getting the current density of a wire with given surface charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge

I found this question, which seemed very easy to me at first, but when I revisited the problem I started to have some doubts about my approach, so I would appreciate any form of discussion or approval for my idea.
The problem is:

> An infinite wire with radius R is rotating with the angular velocity $\omega$ on the x-y-plane and does have a known surface charge density $\sigma(\mathbf r)$. What is the current density $j(\mathbf{r})$ of this wire?

So my idea was to simply use the equation
$$j(\mathbf{r}) = \varrho(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{v},$$
where $\varrho(\mathbf{r})$ is the charge density and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity.
Getting the velocity shouldn't be the issue, since I think I can express it like
$$\mathbf{v}= \dot{\mathbf{r}} = \left(\matrix{-r \omega\sin{\omega t}\\r \omega \cos{wt}\\0}\right).$$
I don't know if it is better to rather use $\mathbf{v}= \mathbf{w}\times\mathbf{r}$ here, though (any comment on this is appreciated).

Though, the main question for me is how do I obtain the charge density $\varrho(\mathbf{r})$ from the given surface charge density $\sigma(\mathbf{r})$. Can I just abuse the symmetry of the problem and say
$$\varrho(\mathbf{r})=\sigma(\mathbf{r})\delta(z)$$
or is this invalid? I am not quite sure about this approach, since it originated from the idea of just comparing the length units between charge density and surface charge density, which often can yield wrong results.

I couldn't really find any similar question, that focuses on the connection between current density, charge density and surface charge density, so I hope this question can be useful to others, too.

Comment: Is this wire rotating about its own center or about an axis in the z direction? In either case, why would there be a current flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given the symmetry of the problem, it is easy to work in [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system)$\leadsto(\rho,\varphi,z)$. If I don't misunderstand the setup, in this coordinates the charge is at the surface $\rho=R$ and it's moving with $\dot\varphi=\omega$ and $\dot z=0$.
2. For the velocity, note that derivating
   $$\mathbf{r}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}R\cos(\omega t)\\R\sin(\omega t)\\z\end{pmatrix}$$
   does not yield OP's result (v1).
3. For the charge density, a general method to find the effective 3-dimensional density $\varrho(\mathbf{r})$ of a 2-dimensional surface charge density $\sigma(\mathbf{r})$ is to multiply $\sigma$ by the Dirac delta of where it is; divided by the corresponding [scale factor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScaleFactor.html). For this particular problem then
   $$\varrho(\mathbf{r})=\sigma(\mathbf{r})\frac{\delta(\rho-R)}{h_\rho}$$
   with $h_\rho=1$ (see e. g. [*MathWorld*:Cylindrical Coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html), Eq. (13)). OP's proposal (v1) was to multiply by $\delta(z)=\delta(z-0)$, but this is not correct since the surface charge is not at $z=0$.

Comment: You are right. I messed up the derivation of $\mathbf{r}$. Also, thank you very much for pointing out the correct way to derive the charge density from a given surface charge density. I wasn't aware of the scale factor.